# Using react-autosuggest, show all the suggestions matching the letters

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, autosuggest

Is there a way to show suggestion list when I typed the first letter A, it should show the letters matching all A.
E.g : I have a list of students such as

```
 {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Dee dee Tanser"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Tobiah Stockwell"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Gregorius Densham"
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Ursula Morrill"
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "Josey Bainton"
    },
```

when a user types the first letter in autosuggest 's', it should render all the matching with that letters(term should match either the first or last name).
Currently it's showing only the first name basis.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `onSuggestionsFetchRequested` prop, to implement the logic you want. Something like this :

```
const students = [
  {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Dee dee Tanser"
  },
  {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Tobiah Stockwell"
  },
];

// Teach Autosuggest how to calculate suggestions for any given input value.
getSuggestions = value => {
    const inputValue = value.trim().toLowerCase();
    const inputLength = inputValue.length;

    if (inputLength === 0) {
        return [];
    }

    return students.filter(student => {
        return student.name.split(' ').some(term => {
            return term.toLowerCase().slice(0, inputLength) === inputValue;
        })
    });
};

  // Autosuggest will call this function every time you need to update suggestions.
  onSuggestionsFetchRequested = ({ value }) => {
    this.setState({
      suggestions: this.getSuggestions(value)
    });
  };

 <Autosuggest
    suggestions={suggestions}
    onSuggestionsFetchRequested={this.onSuggestionsFetchRequested}
    ...
```